# Can there exist a recurrence relation for "sequential search"?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

I'm just confused, cause from my knowledge recurrence is applied mostly to recursive procedures or divide and conquer techniques etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

The cost of searching a list of length zero is zero; the worst-case cost of searching a list of length $n$ is one greater than the cost of searching a list of length $n-1$. So
$$\begin{align*}T(0)&=0 \\ T(n)&=T(n-1)+1\,,\end{align*}$$
with solution being, as you'd expect, $T(n)=n$.

Comment: Heh. Beat me by seconds. Nice explanation.